# Node.js: partition code into smaller functions - is it good?

Tags: performance, node.js

How does this affect performance?
I know that on the client side, it is a good practice, but what about the server side?

Comment: I don't think there is a clear answer to this question. Smaller functions--or just better organized code--is better for the programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's very good. They will be optimized even if they are not hot because it's so cheap to optimize small functions.

The optimization cost scales super-linearly with the size of the function so we could make general statements like optimizing 10 functions with 10 lines is faster than optimizing 1 function with 100 lines.

Also see http://mozakai.blogspot.com/2013/08/outlining-workaround-for-jits-and-big.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it’s good on the server side. If you are so worried about performance that you need to stop using functions, you’re going to have to start writing assembly.

If you actually start to have a problem, profile, benchmark, and modify appropriately. Otherwise, trust V8 to do its job and worry about performance in places that matter, e.g. file access.

Comment: I'm not a maniac :) Just on the side of the server, the computation is quite large (for 1-5 seconds). So began to worry about this problem. It seemed to me that the partition of the code on a huge number of small functions greatly slows down the process.

Comment: @YuriChechulin: It shouldn’t. Could you show some code, or at least describe how you’re using functions, please?